# How can I Close Running Application with 5 fingure Gesture like iPad in Android

Tags: android, gesture

I want to provide a facility to user in Andriod tablet that they can **close** their application with their **5 fingers gesture as like in iPad**.

Is it possible to do in Android Tablet? If possible then How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can do it. Try using [MotionEvent.getPointerCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29), where you can check for the pinter count to be **5**.

Comment: but what about that gesture which is like `closing` action.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: when you detect 5 pointer counter, finish your activity then.

Answer (score 0):

Handling Multi-Touch Gestures
Learn how to detect multi-pointer (finger) gestures.
Dragging and Scaling
Learn how to implement touch-based dragging and scaling.

Open this link here all info is given about how to detect  the type of gesture after detecting 5 fingers........
http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/index.html